# Parent class turned into subclass Pointers C++

Tags: c++

I have a pointer that is set to a new array of objects:

`Animal* pAnimals = new Animal[10];`

The `Animal` class has a subclass called `Dog` , with some more specific functionality.

I need to have some of the objects in the `pAnimals` pointer array to be dogs, but not all of them. Here is what I have tried so far, but with memory leaks:

```
Animal* pAnimals = new Animal[10];

Animal ** pCurrent = &pAnimals;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    *(pCurrent + i) = new Dog();
}
```

I know that `Animal* pAnimals = new Animal[10];` is creating 10 `Animal` objects on the heap, so I will need to delete them later.

Comment: Can't be done. The array contains `Animal` objects. You need a different approach.

Comment: Maybe create an array of pointers to `Animal`s. Then you can make use of polimorphism.

Comment: I want to have an array of `Animal` objects, with some of them being derived classes from `Animal` such as `Dog`, `Cat`, etc.

Comment: On a semi-related note, I would *strongly* advise against using raw arrays and raw pointers. Use `std::vector`/`std::array` and smart pointers

Comment: @UnholySheep good point

Comment: If you have an `Animal` object, you have an `Animal` object. If you have a pointer or reference to an `Animal`, it could be pointing to an object of a derived type (`Dog` or `Cat` or whatever).

Comment: Kevin is correct. In C++ polymorphism does not work as you might see in other language. You have a Animal instance, it is just Animal, and nothing else. The way it works in C++ is you can have pointers to different classes

Comment: If you're used to C# or Java, there is rather a lot that you need to unlearn.

Comment: I am very used to c#, I am pretty new to C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an array of `Animal`-**pointers** first.

```
Animal **pAnimaly = new Animal*[10];
```

Then you can create instances of subclasses of `Animal` like `Dog`. As others suggested, you should consider using `std::vector` or `std:array` instead of ordinary arrays but I assume it's just a lecture so doing some low level stuff for learning is probably fine.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Animal {};
class Dog : public Animal {};

int main()
{
    Animal **pAnimaly = new Animal*[10];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       cout << pAnimaly[i] << endl;
    } 

    cout << "---" << endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
       pAnimaly[i] = new Dog();
    } 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       cout << pAnimaly[i] << endl;

       if (pAnimaly[i] != nullptr) {
           cout << "Freeing memory.." << endl;
           delete pAnimaly[i];       
       }
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to null-check before calling `delete` (also `nullptr` should be preferred over `NULL`)

Comment: @UnholySheep Didn't touch C++ for quite a while. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. Maybe it'll help you.
There is an `Animal` class (quite trvial one but that's just an example) and there are two derived classes. Then in `main` function there is a `vector` of `shared_ptr`s to `Animal`s. Some of those pointers point to `Animal` objects and other to `Dog`s or `Cat`s.

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Animal {
public:
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
};

class Cat : public Animal {
};

int main() {
    std::random_device gen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> dist(0, 2);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>> animals;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        animals.push_back([&] () -> std::shared_ptr<Animal> {
            switch(dist(gen)) {
                case 0:
                    return std::make_shared<Animal>();

                case 1:
                    return std::make_shared<Dog>();

                case 2:
                    return std::make_shared<Cat>();
            }
        }());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why shared pointers though? There's nothing in the question that suggests shared ownership is needed.

Comment: Could be `unique_ptr` but `shared_ptr` is easier for start because you can copy them around almost without any restrictions.

Comment: `shared_ptr` can be easily overused/abused and has unnecessary overhead if you don't need shared ownership. The semantics of `unique_ptr` enforces the idea that there is only one owner, which helps people reading the code understand how it's structured.

Comment: @Kevin that's all correct but if somebody have programmed in Java (or a similar language) and now begins programming in C++ or is generally new to computer programming then `shared_ptr` is much easier to begin with than going into deep water and juggling all kinds of smart pointers.

Comment: @navyblue I get what you're saying but using a `shared_ptr` when it's not necessary is a bad habit. Coming from another language isn't a reason to encourage it, especially because the semantics are different. For example circular references are fine in Java but circular references with shared pointers can cause memory leaks in C++. Might as well teach them to `new` and not `delete` because they don't have to worry about that in Java.

Answer (score -1):

```
Animal* animals[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    animals[i] = new Dog();
}
animals[8] = new Animal();
animals[9] = new Animal();
```

Comment: This answer has no explanation and uses `new` (without `delete`s even) which is discouraged in modern C++

Comment: @Kevin This person is clearly new to C++. The question seems to stem from their confusion about how to declare and manage an array of pointers to polymorphic objects. Why would you want to immediately introduce smart pointers and vectors to somebody like that?

Comment: Smart pointers and vectors really aren't complicated. Regardless, answers containing only code without any explanation are discouraged.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe not to you, but it makes no sense to push them on somebody who doesn't even understand pointers. There is a reason why algebra is taught before calculus and why regular pointers are taught before smart pointers. The accepted answer doesn't have them either and it doesn't matter because that's not what the question was about. As to no explanation, any words would just be fluff: "this is how you declare an array of base class instance pointers" and "this is how allocate an instance of derived class and put it in the array".

Comment: Are you saying that pointers with pointer arithmetic and unknown lifetime (for the pointee) are less complicated than smart pointers with semantic ownership and known lifetime? High level languages use high level structures like vectors because they hide the messiness and are easy to deal with. Modern C++ programmers *don't* need to use `new` at all (in most cases) because these abstractions exist.
And yes, you need an explanation. Something like, "this is what you're doing wrong, this is how to fix it, this is why it fixes the problem". Otherwise there is no understanding.

Comment: No, I'm saying if you're learning C++ you learn pointers first, then smart pointers, like you learn derivatives first, then integrals in calculus. One builds on the other. Is there a book out there, or even an online tutorial, that teaches smart pointers first? I would be curious. And again, the accepted answer, that you didn't comment on, doesn't have them either.

Comment: There's actually a [very nice talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) about how C++ *should* be taught. And I apologize for focusing on your answer.

Comment: OK, I watched most of the talk and I disagree with at least half the points raised there. C++ should not be taught like you would teach Java or Python, ignoring the power of the language and mountains of existing code, and whoever does is doing a disservice to their students, who will eventually have to get a real job and work on real code. The presenter herself seems aware that what she is saying goes against conventional wisdom. So this seems like an insurmountable difference of opinion.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to watch the talk. I don't think it's ignoring the power of the language at all. But let's just agree to disagree and leave it at that.